# Error overloading operator [] for a std vector object

Tags: c++

I have a polygon class defined like this:

```
#include <gVector3.h>   // an array containing three floats (x,y,z coordinates)
#include <vector>

class Polygon {

private:

    std::vector <gVector3> vertices;
    std::vector <gVector3> color;
```

I overloaded the [] operator for this class like so

```
gVector3 Polygon::operator [](unsigned int i) const {
    return vertices[i];
}
```

I've written a simple test case:

```
gVector3 v1(0,0,1), v2(1,1,1), v3(2,0,1);
Polygon *p = new Polygon();
p->push(v1);
p->push(v2);
p->push(v3);
assert(p[0] == v1);   // Assume == for the gVector3 class has been defined correctly
```

Push is defined like so..

```
void Polygon::push(gVector3 vec){
    this->vertices.push_back(vec);
}
```

Bottom line is that this assertion fails, and I'm not sure why. Perhaps I'm misusing the Vector classes indexing method?

Any insights would be helpful!

Comment: Did you overwrite gVector3's operator== ?

Comment: Also, you should return a const reference from your operator[], i.e. const gVector3& Polygon::operator[](size_t i) const {...}

Comment: `p` is a pointer, so `p[0]` is not doing what you expect.

Comment: @juanchopanza hmm I see, so it should be (*p)[0] ?

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Comment: @juanchopanza aha! that was the problem. test passed :)

Comment: Bear in mind that it might be simpler not to use a pointer at all (although I cannot tell for sure from your code sample).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is a pointer, so `p[0]` is the `Polygon` that it points to. I'm surprised that it compiled; I guess there must be some strange implicit type conversion.

You almost certainly don't want to be messing around with pointers and `new`:

```
Polygon p;
p.push(v1);
p.push(v2);
p.push(v3);
assert(p[0] == v1);
```

but if you do for some reason, then you'll need to dereference the pointer before applying `[]`

```
assert((*p)[0] == v1);
```

Comment: Just as an aside, if I don't explicitly initialize the fields "vertices" and "color" in my definition of Polygon(), how does C++ initialize them when I call the constructor *p = new Polygon() ?

Comment: @AmazingVal: Using the default constructor; for `vector`, that gives you an empty vector.

Answer (score 0):

`p[0]` is equivalent to `*(p + 0)`, or just `*p`, so its just giving you the `Polygon` object you allocated. You aren't calling `operator[]` on that object. You need to do `(*p)[0]` instead, which will first get you the `Polygon` object and *then* call `operator[]` on it.